# Spring Boot 1.5.9 and embedded jetty server throwing a null pointer exception at runtime?

Tags: spring-boot, nullpointerexception, jetty

I'm updating our springboot app to 1.5.9 and I'm encountering the following runtime (nullpointer) exception with embedded the jetty server:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:207) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:139) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.sNullPointerExceptionervlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:741) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext$JettyEmbeddedServletHandler.deferredInitialize(JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.java:46) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.deferredInitialize(JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.java:36) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.handleDeferredInitialize(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:205) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.handleDeferredInitialize(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:211) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.start(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:138) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
```

It worked fine with spring boot 1.4.0, so the issue is definitely related to upgrading to 1.5.9?

I have the following in the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>                                                                     
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>                                  
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>                             
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>                                    
        <exclusions>                                                                 
            <exclusion>                                                              
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>                          
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>                  
            </exclusion>                                                             
        </exclusions>                                                                
    </dependency>                                                                    
    <dependency>                                                                     
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>                                  
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>                           
      <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>                                    
    </dependency>
```

Thanks

Comment: I had to specify the version number for the jetty dependency otherwise I was getting an error when running mvn clean install

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me , can you delete your cache(.m2 folder) try to build the project again might be cache issue

this is my POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.stackflow.test</groupId>
<artifactId>DemoSpring1.5.9</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>DemoSpring1.5.9</name>
<description>Stackflow project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried that, but still encountering the issue.. The project is pretty big so it might be the above in combination with one of the other dependencies that is causing the issue. It's a strange one

Comment: Also not sure if this would make a difference but I'm running the code on Linux and Java 8

Comment: I aslo ran in Linux its working fine might because its just sample application , when i see the source code for GenericFilterBean.java class from the ajr [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE] , it seems some logger configuration not done properly the code on 207 line is
[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      this.logger.debug("Initializing filter '" + filterConfig.getFilterName() + "'");
    might be you can check the logger configured

Comment: one more might i guess is anywhere you are using `@Configuration` which is not might be correct to annotate even though you have did `@Component`

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. I tracked it down in the end - it was the Spring AOP that was added to the project as part of this update that caused the null pointer in jetty. It conflicted with some Aspect Audit logging that was already in the project - it was a strange one.